# The text is too bold by DrawString on C#

Tags: c#, image, gdi+, drawstring

I have use GDI `DrawString` method to draw text. When the program is running, the text on the screen seems very good, however once I saved the files to image, the font will be bolder than before. The normal will be bold, the bold will be much bolder. How to deal with this?

```
public override void DrawTo(Graphics g, int x, int y, int flag)
    {
        if (flag == 1)
        {
            Pen dpen = new Pen(Color.FromArgb(128, 0, 0, 0), 1);
            dpen.DashStyle = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.DashStyle.DashDot;
            g.DrawRectangle(dpen, new Rectangle(Bounds.X + x, Bounds.Y + y, Bounds.Width, Bounds.Height));
        }

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Text))
        {

            g.DrawString(Text, Font, new SolidBrush(Color), new Rectangle(Bounds.X + x, Bounds.Y + y, Bounds.Width, Bounds.Height));
        }
    }
```

Comment: Call `g.Clear(...);` ?  Post more code so we have a chance of helping you.

Comment: May be you need to mention the fonts properly (which should be available for both screen and printer)

Comment: Which font(s) are you actually using? How are you treating the DPI?

Comment: I used "Tahoma" font, but no matter what font I use, the text on the saved image will be stronger than normal. I didn't set DPI. You can see here is the DrawString result before saving: [link](http://www.hihisoft.com/1.png), and this is the saved image: [link](http://www.hihisoft.com/2.png)

Comment: We still need to see your relevant code that reproduces the problem.

Comment: Added the code. But the problem is the rendering while saving the file I think.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I got the solution.

```
g.TextRenderingHint = System.Drawing.Text.TextRenderingHint.AntiAlias;
```

Just AntiAlias will solve that.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of setting `TextRenderingHint` to `TextRenderingHint.AntiAlias`, you should prefer to set it to `TextRenderingHint.SingleBitPerPixelGridFit`. For example:

```
g.TextRenderingHint = System.Drawing.Text.TextRenderingHint.SingleBitPerPixelGridFit;
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.
I've tried to use TextRenderingHint, SmoothingMode, TextContrast but it changed nothing.

I've replaced graph.Clear(Color.Transparency) with graph.Clear(Color.White) and Text looks good now.