# Issue with font boldness in image text rendering using ashx handlers

Tags: c#, asp.net, ashx, handlers

I am using the below mentioned code in rendering font inside of an image using handlers. It is coming as expected in development environment. But when I deploy the same in the production the boldness is increased and the text is not good. Any help is appreciated.

```
   string imageFilePathNew = "";

        string firstText = name;
        PointF firstLocation = new PointF(3f, 20f);
        string imageFilePath = Server.MapPath("~/mypath/" + file + ".png");
        imageFilePathNew = Server.MapPath("~/mypathnew/" + file + name + ".png");
        Bitmap bitmap = (Bitmap)Image.FromFile(imageFilePath);//load the image file

        var format = new StringFormat
        {
            Alignment = StringAlignment.Center,
            LineAlignment = StringAlignment.Center
        };
        using (Graphics graphics = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap))
        {
            Font arialFont = new Font("Smallest Pixel-7",3);
            SizeF s = TextRenderer.MeasureText(firstText, arialFont);
            RectangleF rectF1 = new RectangleF(1, 8, 46, 30);
            float fontScale = Math.Max(s.Width / rectF1.Width, s.Height / rectF1.Height);
            using (Font font = new Font(arialFont.FontFamily, arialFont.SizeInPoints / fontScale, GraphicsUnit.Point))
            {

                graphics.DrawString(firstText, font, Brushes.White, rectF1, format);
            }
        }

        //using (Graphics graphics = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap))
        //{
        //    using (Font arialFont = new Font("Smallest Pixel-7", 10))
        //    {
        //        RectangleF rectF1 = new RectangleF(8, 17, 32, 30);
        //        graphics.DrawString(firstText, arialFont, Brushes.Black, rectF1,format);

        //    }
        //}
        Bitmap newbmp = new Bitmap(bitmap);
        //bitmap.Dispose();
        //newbmp.Save(imageFilePathNew,System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);//save the image file

        using (MemoryStream memory = new MemoryStream())
        {
            using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(imageFilePathNew, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.ReadWrite))
            {
                newbmp.Save(memory, ImageFormat.Png);
                byte[] bytes = memory.ToArray();
                fs.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
            }
        }

        return imageFilePathNew;
```

Comment: Are you sure the server has the same font installed?

Comment: I didnt think of it that way... Lemme check and get back .

Comment: @VDWWD no it doesnt help.. :(

Comment: Antialias has solved my problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24748695/the-text-is-too-bold-by-drawstring-on-c-sharp